# Open source software to create videos

Tags: open-source, windows-7, video-editing, graphic-design

I've heard of some pretty great video editors for Linux. However for Windows, I haven't heard much.

I know about Blender, and its video editing capabilities are a rival to any professional software out there, but I am basically talking about a much less complex to use software, one that can be used to compile frames, add videos, quick effects, make some pretty good and quick birthday videos (but not just birthday videos, a whole kind of videos).

I think like slideSHOW 3D (but I don't think it supports adding videos, only allows frames I think and it is not open source).

Is there any open source software as such?

Comment: Free, but not open source: Davinci Resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [**HitFilm 3 Express**](https://hitfilm.com/express).

It works on Windows, it is free and it has some pretty good capabilities. It should be able to do most of the things that you describe. It can trim videos, and add some quick special effects however do there is a pro version that has many more special effects capabilities but if you need something that is free and fairly powerful I would definitely recommend this piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line there is [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) which can do piles but take a look at [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) for some awesome things you can do, (it uses ffmpeg behind the scenes as do a lot of things). You will need [python](https://www.python.org/) and some python libraries listed in the [installation instructions](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html) as well.

The good news:

- Open Source
- Gratis
- Cross Platform including Windows